# GPIO pinout locations

Tags: gpio

Where can I find a list of the GPIO pins' location on the Raspberry Pi?

I have found the following 4 images, which all contradicts each other:

- http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/Raspberry-Pi-GPIO-Layout.png
- http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-zwM_OmpN_SM/UBCSOk1E1PI/AAAAAAAAAQY/GJ4EsfjFcgU/s1600/GPIOs.png
- http://www.johandraaisma.nl/wp-content/uploads/pinout2.png
- http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/freshers/raspberrypi/tutorials/turing-machine/pi_gpio.jpg

Specifically where is GPIO 4 on the Raspberry Pi model B rev. 1 (256 MB RAM)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simon Monk had a recent blog entry on this topic, and provides a pdf download for easy printout. Includes GPIO reference leaflets for revisions 1 and 2:

[Raspberry Pi and Breadboard (Raspberry Leaf)](http://www.doctormonk.com/2013/02/raspberry-pi-and-breadboard-raspberry.html)

Comment: Are you sure rev. 1 doesn't refer to Model A and rev. 2 refers to Model B in that post?

Comment: @Tyilo : Probably not since there is a Model B, rev. 1 and Model B rev. 2, and a Model A rev. 2 (since no model A rev. 1 boards were actually made).

Comment: @goldilocks OK, cool.